# Android app crash while passing intent b/w activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, crash, parameter-passing

When I try to pass the intent to play the song the app is force closing. I am a beginner so unable to find the error. I am getting help from a tutorial, but now I am stuck here. I am trying to get the music from mobile storage and play it on a new activity.
Where am I mistaken?
This activity is receiving the intent value.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        Intent j = getIntent();
        Bundle b = j.getExtras();
        arrayList = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
        int position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

        Uri u;
        u = Uri.parse(arrayList.get(i).toString());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

This is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new  String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
            }
        }else {
                doStuff();
            }
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getMusic();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Player.class).putExtra("pos",i).putExtra("songlist",arrayList));
            }
        });
    }

public void getMusic() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, null, null, null, null);

        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
            int songTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            /*int songLocation = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);*/

            do {
                String currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                String currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist);
                /*String currentLocation = songCursor.getString(songLocation);*/
                arrayList.add(currentTitle + "\n"
                        + "Artist: " + currentArtist);
            }while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        doStuff();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Logcat Detail

```
01-12 23:01:50.658 25516-25516/com.example.name.audioplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-12 23:01:50.658 25516-25516/com.example.name.audioplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.name.audioplayer, PID: 25516
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.name.audioplayer/com.example.name.audioplayer.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.name.audioplayer.Player.onCreate(Player.java:29)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6956)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: add try catch (Throwable e) and show the error in a text box or use addb debugger if u can connect ph to computer and run in debug?

Comment: Can you provide the logcat error?

Comment: I just added the Logcat...

Comment: Make sure you have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions

Comment: Yes! The permission is granted. The listview is displaying all the mp3 in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `mediaPlayer.start()` with an if statement that checks for `null` and the block only gets executed when `mediaPlayer` is not null. In your case the `mediaPlayer` object is `null` possibly because the Uri object `u` doesn't have a valid `Uri`. Insert logs to check its values but firstly insert `if` block to avoid the crash.

Comment: I insert the if statement, now the player isn't crashing anymore but, the songs are not playing.

Comment: That's expected because `mediaPlayer` is null when that `if` statement is reached. Put a log statement like: `Log.d("Uri Value", u.toString());` after `u` is set to know what is the `Uri` that you are obtaining and check if it is a valid one

Comment: Could you please edit the code. I have already shared all the code above.

Comment: Editing the code in question will change the question. Just add `Log.d("Uri Value", u.toString());` before the line `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);` and whenever the statement gets executed, you will get the value of the Uri `u` in the logs where you can check and debug the code.